# Tochange the look and feel Site settings and Visual upgrade options is not available after migrating 2007 to 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

After migrating 2007 to 2010, the 2007 site has been displayed in the sharepoint 2010. But when i am trying to upgrade, the visual upgrade is not available and site settings is also not available.

Please help,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> When you upgrade, either by using in-place upgrade or by using the
>   database attach upgrade method, you can choose to use Visual Upgrade.
>
> During an in-place upgrade, you make the choice to use Visual Upgrade
>   as a step in the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard. The visual
>   upgrade feature is not available in the SharePoint Products
>   Configuration Wizard if you are performing an upgrade on a stand-alone
>   server with built-in database. However, the Visual Upgrade feature is
>   available in this case from the Psconfig command-line tool. You can
>   then use the syntax:

```
psconfig.exe -cmd upgrade [–preserveolduserexperience <true|false>].
```

> During a database attach upgrade, the choice to update to the new user
>   experience or stay in the old user experience is accomplished by using
>   either:
>
> • The Updateuserexperience parameter of the Mount-SPContentDatabase
>   Windows PowerShell cmdlet.
>   • The preserveolduserexperience parameter
>   of the addcontentdatabase Stsadm operation.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607998(v=office.14).aspx

**Psconfig command-line reference (SharePoint Server 2010)**

**upgrade**

> Performs an upgrade of SharePoint 2010 Products. This command is
>   automatically run when you run the SharePoint Products Configuration
>   Wizard if the product has to be upgraded. Takes the following optional
>   parameters:

[-wait]

> If specified, the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard does not
>   return until the upgrade is complete. If not specified, the wizard
>   returns after dispatching a SharePoint Timer Service job to perform
>   the upgrade. To view the upgrade job status, you can access the
>   SharePoint Central Administration Web site by using your Web browser.

[-force]

> If specified, the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard stops any
>   currently running upgrade actions, and then restarts upgrade.

[-reghostonupgrade]

> If specified, the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard will reset
>   all content to the site definition version during the upgrade.

```
[-inplace <v2v|b2b>]
```

> If specified, the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard will
>   perform an in-place upgrade. If v2v is specified, an in-place version
>   to version upgrade is performed. If b2b is specified, an in-place
>   build to build upgrade is performed.

```
[-preserveolduserexperience]
```

> If set to false, the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard will
>   update sites to use the latest SharePoint user experience. If you do
>   not specify this parameter, the default is true.

```
[-passphrase]
```

> Passphrase used to join the server farm. The Passphrase value must be
>   the same on all servers in the farm if the farm is to function
>   correctly.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263093(v=office.14).aspx

if like me and you did a content database upgrade than it would also be available under site actions within the webapplication!

Comment: The Particular Site collection Administrator does not have permission for visual upgrade. Once i change the site collection as Administrator, i Can able to do visual upgrade.